# How to handle several different editions of a particular Item

Tags: mysql, database-design, schema

I'm working on a new database schema.
I'm working on a program to register playing cards into a card collection.
That needs to take into account many different factors.
The bit I have the most trouble with is how to handle several different editions of a particular card.
`+---------------------+
|      Kort info      |
+-----------+---------+
| kort navn | kort ID |
+-----------+---------+
| Clubs     | 1       |
+-----------+---------+
| Diamonds  | 2       |
+-----------+---------+
| Hearts    | 3       |
+-----------+---------+
| Hearts    | 4       |
+-----------+---------+`

Playing cards in a collection usually appear like [this](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CANLQ.png)

`+---------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
| Kort ID | kort navn | antall a | antall b | antall c | antal d |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
| 1       | Clubs     | 1        |          |          |         |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
| 2       | Diamonds  | 2        | 3        |          |         |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
| 3       | Hearts    |          |          | 4        |         |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+
| 4       | Spades    |          |          |          | 13      |
+---------+-----------+----------+----------+----------+---------+`

Each card comes in several editions. And which edition exists are listed in the table ["legal cards"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfxBQ.png).
`+------------------------+
|       legal cards      |
+---------+--------------+
| kort ID | eksisterende |
+---------+--------------+
| 1       | a            |
+---------+--------------+
| 1       | b            |
+---------+--------------+
| 1       | c            |
+---------+--------------+
| 2       | a            |
+---------+--------------+
| 2       | b            |
+---------+--------------+
| 3       | b            |
+---------+--------------+
| 3       | c            |
+---------+--------------+
| 4       | d            |
+---------+--------------+`

The number of cards with edition is stored in the table ["cards in stock"](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbQ5m.png).

`+----------------------------+
|        cards in stock      |
+---------+---------+--------+
| kort ID | versjon | antall |
+---------+---------+--------+
| 1       | a       | 1      |
+---------+---------+--------+
| 2       | a       | 2      |
+---------+---------+--------+
| 2       | b       | 3      |
+---------+---------+--------+
| 3       | c       | 4      |
+---------+---------+--------+
| 4       | d       | 13     |
+---------+---------+--------+`

What I mainly want to ask is this the best solution?
Or is there a better solution I should use?
Or are there certain things in my solution I should look out for?

[list of names of cards](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ortBX.png)

[list of cards in a collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mbQ5m.png)

[list of legal cards in a collection](https://i.stack.imgur.com/UfxBQ.png)

[common way to show results](https://i.stack.imgur.com/CANLQ.png)

Comment: Please [use text, not images/links, for text--including tables & ERDs](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551/3404097). Paraphrase or quote from other text. Give just what you need & relate it to your problem. Use images only for what cannot be expressed as text or to augment text. Images cannot be searched for or cut & pasted. Include a legend/key & explanation with an image. Also, links die. Insert images/links using edit functions. Make your post self-contained.

Comment: Thanks for the tip - updated. Looks like I'm not allowed to post pictures yet. And I'm looking into inheritance.

Comment: It's not a matter of "yet". Don't post an image or link for content that can be given in text.